# how to pass the parameter into batch file?

Tags: batch-file

how to pass the parameter into batch file using java runtime.exec().

> ****Process pp = run.exec("C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Tomcat
>   4.1\bin\RMIClientInvoker.bat C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\bin localhost date");****

when i using this coding error will occur.the parameters are last three part.batch file is RMIClientInvoker.bat. i try in command line the same error has appear but i put the double Qoutes to the parameter the correct o/p display.so any one help how to give the parameter with doubleQoutes.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the double quotes:

```
Process pp = run.exec("\"C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\bin\RMIClientInvoker.bat\" \"C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\bin\" localhost date");
```

The reason this is failing is that runtime exec splits arguments by whitespace (in the same way that java does when you call your `Main` method). Quoting the arguments ensure that it treats the whole of C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\bin\RMIClientInvoker.bat as a single argument and doesn't think it is a set of **four** arguments:

- C:\Program
- Files\Apache
- Group\Tomcat
- 4.1\bin\RMIClientInvoker.bat